# How to properly implement job queue with worker actor

Tags: akka

I have an actor that represent worker for heavy long time job:

```
class Worker extends Actor{

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "doJob" =>
      Thread.sleep(999999)
      sender ! "JobResult"
  }

}
```

I would have limit job queue and explicitly reject user, if queue is full. What is best practice to implement this logic. Should I use bounding mailboxes or some dispatcher, that monitoring job queue? Something like this:

```
class Dispatcher(worker:ActorRef) extends Actor{

  val MAX_JOBS = 10

  var jobs = 0

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case "newJob" =>
      if (jobs >= MAX_JOBS) sender ! "Try later"
      jobs+=1
      worker ! "doJob"

    case "JobResult" =>
      jobs-=1
  }

}
```

Also I not sure how to properly handle failures in that case...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to use a bounded mailbox for the worker actor.

Then you can configure the bounded in a configuration like this:

```
bounded-mailbox {   mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.BoundedMailbox"  
mailbox-capacity = 1000   mailbox-push-timeout-time = 10s  }

akka.actor.mailbox.requirements {  
"akka.dispatch.BoundedMessageQueueSemantics" = bounded-mailbox 
}
```

You can also specify the type of mailbox you want (from the built-in types) or create your own custom mailbox with its own traits and specification. (which messages are treated first etc..)

I think that in your scenario it is best:
1. To create your own mailbox with its own error mechanism and custom cleanup/bounding limitations. (based on bounded mailbox traits)
3. Attach your dispatcher to the custom mailbox you created through configuration.